# Is there any way of adding an DSN in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, java

I am using Java-JDBC and Mysql is my database.. I want to have some Standard ODBC DSN like in windows....Is there a way of setting DSN(Data Source Name) in ubuntu for Mysql/ODBC Drivers ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out that,

Before doing this you need to know following things

1.The host name or IP address of the SQL Server machine.

2.The name of an instance to connect to or the port that the instance is listening on.

3.A valid SQL Server login name and password that can be used to connect to the database you want to access.

Linux ODBC, DSNs are listed in /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini. Installed ODBC drivers will be listed in /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini.

Using the following command one can find the file

```
usr$ find . -iname 'odbc*.ini'
```

and there is also one direct option for installing ODBC bridge drivers and that is

```
sudo apt-get install libmyodbc
```

for Mysql  and for Firebird OBDC driver type following

```
sudo apt-get install libfbclient2
```

This is all you need to do 
See [this link](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/ODBC)  for more details